# Restoring data from partition damaged with dd

Tags: linux, dd, ext4

Last night I have done quite an idiotic thing. In an attempt to delete USB from my friend i have accidentally started

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/MyBootDrive
```

and killed first couple of gigabytes of data from my disk. That data is absolutely not important, i have killed system that needed to be replaced in the first place but. On that partition there is a significant amount of data that should be saved if anyhow possible.

So is there any tool that could make me feel less idiot I obviously am, and save my data from filesystem corrupted like that. I'm aware of some tools but they usually save deleted data, or when partition is changed.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I have managed to rescue everything.

It was not magic, I was just plain lucky. I have realized what I'm doing and stopped command after a bit more than 1 sec. So I have nulled just first 1.4GB of data. That was my boot disk, and naturally my / partition was the only one damaged. So obviously every other partition is left intact. But since my partition table is destroyed everything I was able to see is empty hdd. First thing I tried was to recover partitions with gpart but to no avail.

After that I have found [this](http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/linux-data-recovery.html) article. Using test disk i have managed to save my /home partition and all data from it.

Now everything is finished I have to agree with the end of this artice:

> Well, that would be all. Forget recovery. It's so 70s. Go for backups!

Answer (score 1):

Well ext4 replicates the superblock so you can use tools like gpart to find the partition again.
Then also, ext4 stores all the necessary information to read a block group at the beginning of such group. So theoretically it should be possible to restore all the preserved block groups.

It *might* work to run fsck and point it to a superblock that you might have found (or calculated where it might be).

However, when we lastly tried this, it didn't work for us (but we wrote a new file system over the old one, /dev/zero might be better). We then tried to find files in the raw data, igoring the file system. We could not recover much meaningful data. It is easier for multimedia files than text files though.

Comment: I have just deleted first 1.4 gb of first partition(second and a half after i clicked enter). Everything else should be intact. Gpart did not manage to rescue anything. Any other suggestions?